# Is returning inside an else block safer than just returning after an if block?

Tags: javascript

I had an interesting chat with a C/C++ programmer regarding the following code:

```
function example(maybeTrue) {
    if(maybeTrue) {
        // ...lots of code
        return 1;
    } else {
        // ...lots of code
        return 0;
    }
}


function example(maybeTrue) {
    if(maybeTrue) {
        // ...lots of code
        return 1;
    }
    // ...lots of code
    return 0;
}
```

The first example is what they used in the car industry and apparently is less error prone. I normally write the second example.

So my question is, does anyone have any clear examples stating that one is safer/higher-maintainability/higher-readability than the other?

From what I see, I just see a convention that stuck in the car industry.

Good example of a similar question with a good answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no

Comment: The car industry is not known for its high quality code.

Comment: Yes, unicorns are awesome.

Comment: In this situation I'd want to have a single `return` statement which returns a default value unless the condition matches. **Example:** `function example (maybeTrue) {let returnValue = 0; if (maybeTrue) {returnValue = 1;} return returnValue;}`

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a good place for this question.

Comment: @palaѕн: Not really. Code Review reviews working code asking for tips for improvement, it's not a "coding style opinion" site for hypothetical code choices.

Comment: @Rounin That has two returns?

Comment: @KarlMorrison If you're not certain about final conditions create a reusable function and send a report to the server when it is encountered. Granted, if you're not sure about what conditions would get to this point either the problem is too convoluted or your code could use improvement. Good luck!

Comment: This is opinion based, but also situation based. I think the first one is less likely to make human errors, as you would never forget to return something but if the function grows in the future, the second one is better.  But that's just my opinion.

Comment: If there is a lot of code in both conditions, I'd break out the code parts into new functions/methods and do this: `maybeTrue ? doA() : doB()`. If however one part is big and the other is small, I'll go with your second option and put the small part first.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I see this also as opinion based. But for example on a different topic, this was a good example: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP19-C.+Use+braces+for+the+body+of+an+if%2C+for%2C+or+while+statement

Comment: And: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no

Comment: @KarlMorrison Yeah but the topic you linked has reasons why you shouldn't use the brackets. This could lead to confusing results. However in this case. It's always clear I think. However if there is a lot of code ,as you said, maybe split up that code in two functions. In conclusion: some opinion based question can be talked about in an abstract way. This is too situational based to give one clear opinion.

Comment: The snippet with the `else` block makes it clear that the second part of the code is executed conditionally only. An early return might work well if there is not much code.